# How to not repeat sns.kdeplot computation when looping through multiple method?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, seaborn, kdeplot

I need to visualize a dataset distribution using several `multiple` method. Then I created a `multiplehue_kdeplots` function to generate three visual of the same dataset. It's working as expected, but as far as I can see on large dataset, the distribution is calculated three time (which takes time). How could I calculate it once and only change the way the distribution is displayed ?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

np.random.seed(42)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'category': np.random.randint(0, 4, size=500),
    'value': np.random.uniform(-10, 10, size=500)
})

def multiplehue_kdeplots(df, val_col, cat_col,
                         mults = ['layer', 'stack', 'fill'], leg_idx = None, pal = None,
                         **kwargs):
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=len(mults), sharex=True, **kwargs)
    if len(mults) == 1:
        axs = [axs]
    
    for i, m in enumerate(mults):
        leg = None
        if leg_idx == i:
            leg = True
        sns.kdeplot(data=df, x=val_col, hue=cat_col, fill=True, alpha=0.5, multiple=m,
            legend = leg, palette=pal, ax=axs[i])
        axs[i].set_title(mults[i].title())
        axs[i].set_ylabel('Density')

    fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.3)
    plt.show()

multiplehue_kdeplots(df, 'value', 'category')
```

Comment: If the speed difference is really very important for you, you could calculate the kde via scipy and do the scalings manually.  But probably implementing and testing will take more time than just running the existing seaborn code.

Comment: While testing the layout and exploring the dataset, you can reduce the data (e.g. via `sns.kdeplot(data=df.sample(10000), ...)`) and only at the end take the full dataset into account.  Often, a large sample is hardly distinguishable from the full dataset.